# Best View subclass for a newsfeed, is it WebView?

Tags: android, webview, android-listview

I've been putting together some ListView's and Adapters and Layouts, and I had a thought.

Is this all better done with a WebView?

Is it "lazy" to resort to a WebView instead of trying to make something pretty using Android XML layouts?

Does the Facebook app, for example, power most everything through a WebView? I notice it looks as if it does, due to the style of the links.

If not the WebView, what's the recommended View subclass for that kind of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what your purpose is.

Are you making a cross platform application? If so, it might be a good idea to make your layouts in HTML and make the device specific features in the local language. I believe this is what the Facebook application does because the application looks the same on most platforms, but it still has Android specific menu buttons and search features. This is also what the Khan Academy iPad application does.

If you're just trying to make an Android application though, it would be much easier to debug issues if you were using Android specific dialogs since rather than making complex HTML pages that can work on all sizes of Android devices you can use the nice features given to you by the SDK (RelativeLayout/LinearLayout/etc).

Consider what your actual purpose is and move from there.